# What's the technical explanation behind this?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Can someone explain why the two dfs below are not equal any more?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(100,4),
    columns=list('ABCD')
   )

df.to_csv('data.csv')

# and then
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df1.equals(df)
False
```

Comment: Check the individual columns, compare dtypes, ... Something has changed somewhere, so you need to investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing you need to pass `index=False` in your `to_csv`.

Even if you pass that and get the same columns in your `df` and `df1` even then you may get `False` with `equals`. Thats because of the floating point precision I believe. I don't see in the documentation for [`equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) to specify the precision.

If you try with `integers` with the code below, you can see you will get True. Because comparison with integers can be made accurately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(100, size=(5,4)),
    columns=list('ABCD')
   )

df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)

# and then
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

print(df1.equals(df))

True
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, floating point precision is the explantion to this.